# JS - how is [].concat(...arr) different from [...arr]?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am going through JavaScript course on freecodecamp and I came across this ['Steamroller' challenge](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/intermediate-algorithm-scripting/steamroller). Coming from python I really like one-liner solutions so I managed to write one for this challenge:

```
function steamrollArray(arr) {
  return Array.isArray(arr) ? [].concat(...arr.map(steamrollArray)) : arr;
}

steamrollArray([1, [2], [3, [[4]]]]) // returns [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

The goal is basically to flatten an array of arbitrary depth. What puzzles me though (still new to JavaScript) is why seemingly similar code behaves very differently. Something I wrote at the beginning doesn't work, but code I arrived at through trial and (mostly) error works:

```
[...arr.map(steamrollArray)] // this doesn't work, returns an unchanged array

[].concat(...arr.map(steamrollArray)) // this works, returns a flat array
```

This seems strange to me because 'unfolding' the recursion would suggest it should be the other way around

```
[...arr.map(steamrollArray)] 
[1, ...[2], ...[3, ...[...[4]]]] // this should work

[].concat(...arr.map(steamrollArray))
[].concat(...[1, [].concat(...[2]), [].concat(...[3, [].concat(...[].concat(...[4]))])]) // what 'is going on'
```

Can anyone please explain this behaviour?

Comment: Did you read the [description of concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat#description) carefully?

Answer (score 1):

Quote from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat#description):

> Then, for each argument, its value will be concatenated into the array — for normal objects or primitives, the argument itself will become an element of the final array; **for arrays ..., each element of the argument will be independently added to the final array.**

You can observe this behavior below; both give us `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, even though the second call uses an array.

```js
console.log([1, 2, 3].concat(4, 5, 6));
console.log([1, 2, 3].concat([4, 5, 6]));
```

If you want to concat the whole array, then you must wrap it in another array:

```js
console.log([1, 2, 3].concat([[4, 5, 6]])); // [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]
```

So how does this relate to your problem? Well... If we have an array like `[1, 2, [3, 4], 5, [6]]`, and we spread that into `concat`, we would get something like this:

```js
console.log([].concat(1, 2, [3, 4], 5, [6]));
```

... essentially "flattening" it by one level. Your function is recursive, so it flattens the array like this until it is completely flat.

Answer (score 1):

`Array.prototype.concat`'s arguments, if they are arrays, are essentially flattened into the resulting array. So

```
[2].concat(3, [4, 5])
```

results in `[2, 3, 4, 5]`. Similarly

```
[].concat(3, [4, 5])
```

results in `[3, 4, 5]`.

But spreading an array into another array does not perform such flattening on *each element of the spread array*.

```
const arr = [3, [4, 5]];
const newArr = [...arr];
```

takes each element of `arr` and puts it into a new array - but that's it, giving you `[3, [4, 5]]` - the same values of the original array, but inside a different array.

For the code in your question:

```
[...arr.map(steamrollArray)]
```

fails because it's `steamrollArray` that does the flattening - but you'll also need to flatten each returned array. For example, if you pass in `[[1, 2], [3, [4, 5]]]`:

```
[...[[1, 2], [3, [4, 5]]].map(steamrollArray)]
[...[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]]
```

which doesn't flatten the top level. But `[].concat(...arr.map(steamrollArray))` works because `concat` (shallowly) flattens *each of its array arguments* into the result.

Answer (score 0):

So others answer your question, but here are simplified code

```js
const steamrollArray1 = arr => Array.isArray(arr) ? [].concat(...arr.map(steamrollArray1)) : arr;

const steamrollArray2 = arr => Array.isArray(arr) ? arr.flat(Infinity) : arr;

console.log(
  steamrollArray1([1, [2], [3, [[4]]]])
); // returns [1, 2, 3, 4]

console.log(
  steamrollArray2([1, [2], [3, [[4]]]])
); // returns [1, 2, 3, 4]
```